# lightning:recordeditform not populating lookup fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Here are steps what i did
1. Create a lightning component with `lightning:recordeditform`. Inside this form `lightning:inputfield` will hold values.
2. Assign this component to record detail page or quick action as per `objectApiName` in `lightning:recordeditform`. 
3. Consider inside that form some fields are lookup fields. Remove those fields from page layout.
5. Now open any record and now see that component section. None of the lookup are populated.
Is anybody face the same issue and have solution help me.
**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"                                   
                                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                          recordTypeId="0127F000000UdRuQAK"
                                          objectApiName="Opportunity">
                <lightning:messages />
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account_Lookup_Test__c"/>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account_Lookup_Test2__c"/>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Contact_Lookup_Test__c" /><br/>
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Contact_Lookup_Test2__c" />
            </lightning:recordEditForm>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: It's working for me. Are you sure about the recordTypeId value?

Comment: I removed recordTypeId  and tried again it gives the same issue. Have removed all those fields from page layout first?

Comment: Where are you rendering this component? Did you add it to the opportunity record page?

Comment: yes. It's on opportunity record page.

Comment: `<lightning:recordForm />` also having the same issue.

Comment: Anyone able to find a workaround or resolution to the problem. I'm also using <lightning:recordForm /> and getting an exception due to this "Field: RecordTypeId is not a valid lookup field"

Comment: Here is a one of the trick..<br/>Embed hidden `<lightning:recordViewForm>` in your code. Which is holding your lookup fields just like below code.

        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="003XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact">
            <div class="slds-box">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Account.Id" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="LookupField__c" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordViewForm> @NishantSinghPanwar

Answer (score 1):

`lightning:recordEditForm` doesnt render those fields that are not contained in the related layout.

That layout is defined by the RecordTypeId (which is the default one in case you dont chose any).

Comment: Yup! Can we overcome that. Also it populated once that component get refreshed. In detail just edit any field and save it. Now record page will refreshed without page load. Now see the component section some of those are populated. I don't know what is the logic behind this.

Comment: So, you mean during edition just some of the changed fields are being refreshed?

Comment: I means to say if the component get refreshed without page reload it populate some fields. You can use $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire() to refresh the component. Just create button in that component,execute $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire() in onclick method from js controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one of the trick..
Embed hidden `<lightning:recordViewForm>` in your code. Which is holding your lookup fields just like below code.

```
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact">
        <div class="slds-box">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Account.Id" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="LookupField__c" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Comment: "LookupField__c", is this a new custom field you created? What are you storing in this?

Comment: yes LookupField__c is a custom lookup field.  Here we are not going to store anything. Basic idea is "<lightning:recordViewForm>" does not have issue with lookup fields whether it may or may not be in layout. So if we load the lookup fields inside the  "<lightning:recordViewForm>" it will populate lookup fields on "<lightning:recordForm />" or `lightning:recordeditform`. Try this. @NishantSinghPanwar